# How do I determine a unit's current health?

Tags: civilization-5

This may sound obvious, but how can you tell how much health your units have in Civilization V?

Answer (score 8):

There's several ways to determine a unit's hit points:
[image]

In the lower left hand side of the screen, you'll see an info panel with a small bar on the right side.  If you hover over this bar, you'll see the unit's current hit points.

When looking at an area on the map, only damaged units will show a bar with their current hit points.  You can see the musketman garrisoned in Onondaga and the cannon southwest of it are both damaged, and they both have hit point indicators to the right of their unit symbols.

Hit points on almost all units are measured on a scale of 10, but unit strength, alongside defense and attack modifiers, limit how much damage they deal and receive from other units.

Cities also have hit points, which you can gauge by the bar above the name of the city.  In this case, directly above the word Onondaga you can see that that city has recently taken damage which it has not yet recovered from.  City hit points are measured differently, and you can gauge a city's relative strength by the number next to the shield on top of the name.

Comment: What do you mean by "*almost* all units"? I thought *all* units have 10 hitpoints and all cities have 20.

Comment: @Oak, I was thinking there might be some special cases - I don't remember offhand if things like workers, great people, and missiles have "hit points" in the standard sense.

Comment: Not sure about missiles, but workers and great people do have HP. They take damage in the normal way, but have the disadvantage of instant death if an enemy unit moves onto the same space

Comment: Also @Oak, I don't know that all cities have 20 health.  I haven't exhaustively tested it, but I bombarded a city with 25 strength enough to knock 20 health off of it, and it still had health left.

Comment: @agent86 that's 'cause you cannot destroy a city unless you occupy it with units...

Comment: @Nacho, no, it wasn't just that it had a tiny sliver of health left, it had a nontrivial percentage.  I'm aware that you can't take the last HP off with a siege unit.

Comment: Only melee units can remove the last hp from a city. So once a city has 1 hp, ranged attacks no longer do anything to the city (and also do net give xp to the attacker). Melee attacks can lower the city to 0 HP, in which case it normally gets captured. The exception is gunships - those are melee units but they explicitly cannot capture cities, so (as far as I know) they are the only unit in the game that can lower a city to 0 hp - where its health bar is completely empty - while still not capturing it. In any case, as far as I know, all cities have 20 hp and all units have 10.

Comment: @Oak, I'm aware you have to use a melee unit to capture - perhaps my comment was hidden.  I believe, however, that the city still had multiple HP left after 21 damage done in a single turn (ie, the bar was still yellow, and I could bombard it and still get it to decrease).  We're pretty off-topic here though, so we should probably either take this to chat, or open a new question :)

Comment: Ah I see what that comment meant now. Anyway yes we can delete everything here :) In any case, I'm pretty sure all units have 10 hp. Regarding cities we can discuss that on chat sometime!